# What will happen if we change the order of variable in the double integral?

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

If we change the order of variable $(x,y)$ to $(y,x)$ in the double integral, how will it behave? Will limits be changed due to changing the variable?

Comment: Yes, it most certainly will.

Comment: You can't change the order of integration here because the limits of the inner integral depend on $y$.

Comment: @K.defaoite You can, with a trick.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Fubini-Tonelli assumptions,

$$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} f(x,y)\,dxdy=\int_0^1\int_{-1}^11_A(x,y)f(x,y)\,dxdy=\int_{-1}^1\int_{0}^11_A(x,y)f(x,y)\,dydx$$

Where $A=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb [0,1]\times[-1,1]\,:\, -\sqrt{1-y^2}\le x\le\sqrt{1-y^2}\right\}$. Notice that $$\begin{cases}0\le y\le 1\\ -1\le x\le 1\\ -\sqrt{1-y^2}\le x\le\sqrt{1-y^2}\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}0\le y\le \sqrt{1-x^2}\\ -1\le x\le 1\end{cases}$$

and therefore $A=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[-1,1]\,:\, 0\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}\}$. Therefore, since $0\le \sqrt{1-x^2}\le 1$, $$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^11_A(x,y)f(x,y)\,dydx=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} f(x,y)\,dydx$$